# How to verify json data format and type using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

json data :

```
    [
       {
            "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
            "IsResetNeeded": null,
            "ProductType": "12345",
            "Product": {
                "Family": "12345"
            },
            "Device": {
                "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                    "DeviceUpdateStatus": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateInProgress": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateProgress": null,
                    "LastDeviceUpdateId": null
                },
                "ManualAdded": {
                    "Value": false
                },
                "Location":{
                    "Value":"bangalore"
                }
         }
    ]
```

How to verify "value" key is present or not in the above json data using python.
If "value" key is not present in the above json data then i need to verify that json data format should look like below

```
[
       {
            "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
            "IsResetNeeded": null,
            "ProductType": "12345",
            "Product": {
                "Family": "12345"
            },
            "Device": {
                "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                    "DeviceUpdateStatus": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateInProgress": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateProgress": null,
                    "LastDeviceUpdateId": null
                },
                "ManualAdded": false,

                "Location":"bangalore"

         }
    ]
```

Updated json data

```
[{
    "Id": "12",
    "Type": "DevicePropertyChangedEvent",
    "Payload": [{
        "DeviceType": "producttype",
        "DeviceId": 2,
        "IsFast": false,
        "Payload": {
            "DeviceInstanceId": 2,
            "IsResetNeeded": false,
            "ProductType": "product",
            "Product": {
                "Family": "home"
            },
            "Device": {
                "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                    "DeviceUpdateStatus": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateInProgress": null,
                    "DeviceUpdateProgress": null,
                    "LastDeviceUpdateId": null
                },
                "ManualAdded": false,
                "Name": {
                    "Value": "Jigital60asew",
                    "IsUnique": true
                },
                "State": null,
                "Location": "bangalore",
                "Serial": null,
                "Version": "2.0.1.100"
            }
        }
    }]
}]
```

Updated json data please have a look...For updated json the accepted answer should be modified.please help

How can i verify this?

Comment: Is it a mix of caps-case and lowercase (`"Value"` vs `"value"`)?

Comment: No ..it's only "Value"

Comment: You have two different schemas for "ManualAdded"?

Comment: yes...first i need to check  "value" key is present or not in the json data, if "value" key is not present then i should verify the data format should look like second schema.

Comment: @StephenRauch please help me...I am stuck from two days

Comment: Are we validating or converting?

Comment: @StephenRauch Only validating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the record is in one of the formats, you can do:

#### Code:

```
def validate_record_schema(record):
    device = record.get('Device', {})
    manual_added = device.get('ManualAdded', None)
    location = device.get('Location', None)
    if isinstance(manual_added, dict) and isinstance(location, dict):
        if 'Value' in manual_added and 'Value' in location:
            return True
    return isinstance(manual_added, bool) and isinstance(location, str)
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    {
        "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
        "IsResetNeeded": None,
        "ProductType": "12345",
        "Product": {
            "Family": "12345"
        },
        "Device": {
            "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                "DeviceUpdateStatus": None,
                "DeviceUpdateInProgress": None,
                "DeviceUpdateProgress": None,
                "LastDeviceUpdateId": None
            },
            "ManualAdded": {
                "Value": False
            },
            "Location": {
                "Value": "bangalore"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
        "IsResetNeeded": None,
        "ProductType": "12345",
        "Product": {
            "Family": "12345"
        },
        "Device": {
            "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                "DeviceUpdateStatus": None,
                "DeviceUpdateInProgress": None,
                "DeviceUpdateProgress": None,
                "LastDeviceUpdateId": None
            },
            "ManualAdded": False,
            "Location": "bangalore"
        }
    },
    {
        "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
        "IsResetNeeded": None,
        "ProductType": "12345",
        "Product": {
            "Family": "12345"
        },
        "Device": {
            "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                "DeviceUpdateStatus": None,
                "DeviceUpdateInProgress": None,
                "DeviceUpdateProgress": None,
                "LastDeviceUpdateId": None
            },
            "ManualAdded": {
            },
            "Location": {
                "Value": "bangalore"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "DeviceInstanceId": 5,
        "IsResetNeeded": None,
        "ProductType": "12345",
        "Product": {
            "Family": "12345"
        },
        "Device": {
            "DeviceFirmwareUpdate": {
                "DeviceUpdateStatus": None,
                "DeviceUpdateInProgress": None,
                "DeviceUpdateProgress": None,
                "LastDeviceUpdateId": None
            },
            "ManualAdded": 0,
            "Location": "bangalore"
        }
    }
]



print([validate_record_schema(r) for r in data])
```

#### Results:

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: Previously "ManualAdded" and "Location" keys are inside Device but now keys are inside "Payload". How can i modify ur script to new json..Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here are two issues to solved.

1. walk through all element in json
2. change element value if the value contains the key `"Value"`

---

```python
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


# solve first issue    
def walk(node):
    for key, item in node.items():
        if isinstance(item, dict) and 'Value' in item:
            # I don't understand what is your 'verify' mean
            # I just change the value, you should 'verify' it here
            node[key] = change_if_value_exist(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            walk(item)


# solve second issue   
def change_if_value_exist(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if 'Value' in d:
            return d['Value']
    return d    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # json_txt is your input text 
    json_data = json.loads(json_txt, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    walk(json_data[0])
    new_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)
    print(new_json)
```

Comment: {"ManualAdded": {"Value": false)} this is my actual data and i am removing "Value" key from data so after removing "Value" key the data will  be {"ManualAdded": false}...I want to verify data schema